# In a FormView, how to change the property of a Label in the ItemTemplate?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

In ASP.NET, I have a FormView which is bound to an ObjectDataSource. The FormView has an ItemTemplate with a Delete button, and a Label. I'm handling the OnItemDeleted event of the FormView to detect if my business class throws an exception upon deletion. If an exception is detected, I change the text of the Label to whatever the exception message is.

Well, it's just not working.

I detect the Exception fine, but the Text of the Label never gets changed. When the page reloads, the default text stays. I have also tried to rebind the FormView with DataBind() after assigning the new Text, but it's not working either.

In a desperate attempt at tracking the problem, I've taken the Label out of the FormView and it's working fine.

What I am doing wrong?

ASPX page:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="MyObjectDataSource" 
    TypeName="MyScopeRepository" 
    SelectMethod="GetById"
    DeleteMethod="Delete"
    runat="server">

    <SelectParameters>
        <%-- The id param here is from a DropDownList, not included in the example for clarity. --%>
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="id" Type="Int32" ControlID="MyDropDownList" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>

<asp:FormView ID="MyFormView" DataSourceID="MyObjectDataSource"
    RenderOuterTable="false"
    DataKeyNames="Id"
    OnItemDeleted="MyFormViewItemDeleted"
    runat="server">

    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button CssClass="Button Small" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete" runat="server" /><br />
        <asp:Label ID="ErrorLabel" Text="Default text" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void MyFormViewItemDeleted(object sender, FormViewDeletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Exception != null && e.Exception.InnerException is RepositoryException)
    {
        Label errorLabel = (Label)MyFormView.FindControl("ErrorLabel");
        errorLabel.Text = e.Exception.InnerException.Message;
        e.ExceptionHandled = true;

        // I also tried this to no avail.
        //MyFormView.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot!

EDIT: I've checked all events fired by the FormView when clicking the Delete button and here is what I got:

1. OnInit
2. OnItemCreated
3. OnLoad
4. OnItemCommand
5. OnItemDeleting
6. OnItemDeleted
7. OnItemCreated
8. OnDataBound
9. OnPreRender
10. OnUnload

So we can see that OnItemCreated gets fired twice, and the second time it's fired is AFTER OnItemDeleted, which means that whatever change I make is overwritten, I suppose. Now how am I supposed to handle that?

Comment: @md1337 check whether the execution comes into the loop with break point...

Comment: is it something present in form view like data bound event in grid view ?

Comment: @Pandiya- What loop? I have verified that the execution reaches MyFormViewItemDeleted and specifically the errorLabel.Text line, if that's what you mean.

Comment: @Andrew- Sorry man I don't get it.

Comment: I havent worked with form view, but have worked immensely with grid view. The grid views data bound binds the whole datasource every time grid gets changed. So I thought why cant ondatabound event can used in form view too for the same purpose.

Comment: @Andrew- OnDataBound can't be used since OnItemDeleted is the only place where I can catch the exception raised by my business class, which is the reason for changing the Label in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is working solution (You may want to improve it):

```
<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" 
    AllowPaging="true" OnItemDeleted="FormView1_ItemDeleted" ondatabound="FormView1_DataBound" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        Key:
        <asp:Label ID="KeyLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Key") %>' />
        <br />
        Value:
        <asp:Label ID="ValueLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Value") %>' />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete"
            Text="Delete" />
        <hr />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="does not work"></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetList"
    DeleteMethod="Delete" TypeName="MyProject.Repository">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="key" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

codebehind:

```
public string MyProperty { get; set; }
        protected void FormView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(MyProperty))
            {
                Label l = FormView1.FindControl("Label1") as Label;
                l.Text = "it works. " + MyProperty;
                MyProperty = null;
            }
        }

        protected void FormView1_ItemDeleted(object sender, FormViewDeletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Exception != null)
            {
                MyProperty = e.Exception.Message;
                e.ExceptionHandled = true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: In the OP I mentioned that I tried that and that it works, but I need the error message under the field in the FormView.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one way is to add another public field to the data source object called "Error", then in `MyFormViewItemDeleted` change the proper value and re-bind the FormView.

As far as I can see it should work, though there *might* be easier/more simple way.

Comment: I suppose this is the same as adding a private variable to my code-behind class to hold the message until we reach the ItemCreated event, at which point I will stick the message to the Label. I don't like this solution. it feels like I'm circumventing ASP.NET with some MacGyver code, but I don't see any other way.

Comment: @md - can't see any other way too.. hope someone will come along with something though. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did after modifying the code a bit. In the code behind, declared a Field in the Class: private string str_feedbackmsg;

```
try
    {
        cnn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(dbcmd, cnn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        str_feedbackmsg = "Database Work Done!";
    }
    catch (SqlException err)
    {

        str_feedbackmsg = "Database Error: Please Notify the Site Administrators.";
    }
    finally
    {
        cnn.Close();
    }
```

Then in the Databound event for the FormView:

```
protected void gv_main_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        Label l = fv_main.FindControl("lbl_feedback") as Label;
        l.Text = str_feedbackmsg;
    }
}
```